# Densityplot with two argument function

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the heat map of a two-variable function which has two arguments, but the function is continuous on the transition line.

However, the densityplot put no color on the transition line.

Here is an example

```
r[x_, y_] = If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, x^2 + y^2, If[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, 1]]
DensityPlot[r[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This gives the following image
[image]

I want the white circle to be coloured as 1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange.  Use the option, `Exclusions -> None`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
r[x_, y_] = If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, x^2 + y^2, If[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, 1]];
DensityPlot[r[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]